# Calling pyuic4 in a for loop to generate all py files | Calling .bat from python

Tags: python, batch-file, for-loop, pyuic, pyrcc

I want to create a short script that loops over all .ui and .qrc files in a folder, and calls pyuic4 and pyrcc4 respectively for each file thus generating the corresponding .py files.

EDIT months later after i learned more python:

```
import shutil
import os


# pyrcc5 pixels.qrc -o pixels_rc.py && pyuic5 mainWindowGUI.ui -o MainWindowGUI.py && pyuic5 titleBarGUI.ui -o TitleBarGUI.py

command = 'pyrcc5 pixels.qrc -o pixels_rc.py'

for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if file.endswith('ui'):
        filename = file.split('.')[0]
        command = f'{command} && pyuic5 {filename}.ui -o {filename}.py'

print(f'\n Executing: {command} \n')

try:
    result = os.system(command)
    if result is 0:
        pass
except Exception as e:
    print('Error {e}')

print('\n Done.')
```

Comment: Because there is whitespace in the path, i would expect you wrap the path in double quotes.

Comment: there is no path directly given. where do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# generate something like this and the run it
# @echo off
# pyrcc5 pixels.qrc -o pixels_rc.py && pyuic5 window.ui -o window.py && pyuic5 dialog.ui -o dialog.py

command = f'pyrcc.exe Design/pixels.qrc -o GeneratedFiles/pixels_rc.py'

for file in os.listdir(Path(os.getcwd()+'/Design')):
    if file.endswith('ui'):
        filename = file.split('.')[0]
        command = command + f" && pyrcc.exe Design/{filename}.ui -o GeneratedFiles/{filename}.py"

try:
    result = os.system(command)
    if result == 0:
        pass
except Exception as e:
    print('Error {e}')

print('\n Done.')
```